# I cannot install my Brother DCP-J552N printer

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

When I go to Add Printer, my printer shows up.  I click Forward and it says Choose Driver.  I have not been able to locate a PPD download for this printer.  When I try "Search for a printer driver to download", no matches are found.  When I select printer from database and choose "Brother" and then click Forward, on the next page my printer is not listed under Choose Driver.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to hook up my printer?

Thank you.

Comment: You might check here: http://support.brother.co.jp/j/b/downloadtop.aspx?prod=dcpj552n&c=jp&lang=ja

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I went to that site (I had actually been there several times before), but I am still competely confused.  I tried the chat service, but they said they will not deal with linux there.  I have been working on this for two days now and I am really frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the cupswrapper source code file at the link I gave above. Right-click the tar.gz package and select 'Extract Here.' Open the extracted folder and find the folder PPD. Within is the printer's .ppd file.

Now try to install the printer again and instead of finding the driver from the database, select instead, 'Provide PPD file.' Select the .ppd file you extracted. The printer should install and print.